# Unable to find properties file

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

Where is config.properties stored ?

I can't seem to track it down. I am able to read from it so I know it exists.

I use maven for dependency management, the WAR file is built using Eclipse default build action.

I checked all the following locations  in the Navigator view, Package Explorer and the WAR file:

- /
- /src
- /WebContent
- /WebContent/Web-INF

---

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
OutputStream output = null;
try {

    output = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");

    // set the properties value
    prop.setProperty("os", OsDetect.getPropertyOsName());

    // save properties to project root folder
    prop.store(output, null);

} 
catch (IOException io) {
    io.printStackTrace();
} 
finally {
    if (output != null) {
        try {
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it on your classpath?

Comment: if you are using the linux or mac os , then try using the command `find . -name "config.properties"` in your code root folder.

Comment: have you checked src/main/resources ?

Comment: Same, for me it's always stored in : src/main/resources

Comment: @NickDiv In my case I see a /src folder no src/main

Comment: Might need to change my folder filter settings

Comment: Didnt you get any result from running the find command by AmitK

Comment: @NickDiv I am on a PC , and no .

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting the file in my WEB-INF/lib folder and manually edit it with the key/value properties. Placing it in the WEB-INF makes it unavailable for direct Servlet request.

To read the from the properties file I do the following :

```
    private final String PROPERTIESPATH ="/WEB-INF/lib/config.properties";
    private final Properties properties = new Properties();

    private void loadProperties(ServletContextEvent context) {

    ....    
       InputStream   input = context.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(PROPERTIESPATH);
       properties.load(input);   
    ....

   }
```